# Maintaining the default home screen after reinstall an android app

Tags: android, preferences, homescreen

I have an app used to corporate purposes, which is pre configurated to be the default home screen.

They do that by:

- Installing the app
- Pressing Exit
- Pressing Home in the screen that appears
- On the "Complete action using" screen, selecting the app and checking the "Use by default for this action"

The problem is that I have to make a remote update of this app, the installation works perfectly but the home screen is reseted and the "Complete action using" screen, comes back.

There's any way, to prevent the loss of the default home screen preference?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that on stock roms